# My angular ng-repeat div is commented in the browser

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I searched for few days and have not been able to get a solution. I think this problem is code specific.
I'm new to angular and working with using angular 1.6.

I'm sorry my post is like this, This is my first post on stack overflow

```js
var app = angular.module('productApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://localhost/js/database.json")
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.datad = response.products;
        return $scope.datad;
    })
})

//database.json file

{
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "toy z",
            "price" : "1999",
            "image":"toys/007.png",
            "category": "Toys" 
        },
        {
            "name": "Magic Swan",
            "price" : "200",
            "image":"toys/006.png",
            "category": "Toys" 
        },
        {
            "name": "Ben10 Watch",
            "price" : "499",
            "image":"toys/005.png",
            "category": "Toys" 
        }
    ]
 }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body ng-app="productApp">
 <div ng-controller="myController" >
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="p in datad">
          {{p.name}}  {{p.price}}
      </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And... can you show a [mcve]? What's your code? Preferably with an instruction how to reproduce that error on other machines.

Comment: problem is code specific.. So where is the code ?

Comment: Share your code? Might be script loading issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all , make sure url of database.json you can use relative path as below code for example.

and you need to change also

```
$scope.datad = response.products;
```

to

```
$scope.datad = response.data.products;
```

response object contain all information about http request and result will coming into **data** object.

finally no need to return $scope.datat, because products assigned to scope.

```
$http.get("./database.json")
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);// print response to check.
    $scope.datad = response.data.products;
})
```

Comment: it worked, Thanks alot man. You saved my project